# Problems with "devise_for", "devise_scope"!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to customize my routes in devise. I've tried to use devise_scope :user, but it dind't work. So I changed to devise_for, and skiped the custom routes (registrations, confirmations, passwords, session) and it worked. But then, an error show up in my views, when i wass calling "session_path" for example. It was making a form redirecting to "session.user", that makes no sense.

Here is the code:

```
  #routes.rb

  devise_for :users, :path => '', :skip => [ :passwords, :registrations, :confirmations] do
    post   "account/password",      :to => "devise/passwords#create"
    get    "account/password/new",  :to => "devise/passwords#new", :as => "new_password"
    get    "account/password/edit", :to => "devise/passwords#edit", :as => "edit_password"
    put    "account/password",      :to => "devise/passwords#update"
    post   "account",               :to => "users/registrations#create"
    get    "sign_up",               :to => "users/registrations#new"
    delete "account",               :to => "users/registrations#destroy"
    post   "confirmation",          :to => "devise/confirmations#create"
    get    "confirmation/new",      :to => "devise/confirmations#new", :as => "new_confirmation"
    get    "confirmation",          :to => "devise/confirmations#show"
  end
```

New session view:

```
  #users/sessions/new.html.erb
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :format=>:user, :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
```

What do I do? What happened to "devise_scope" doesn't work correctly (The error it was showing up was "Could not find devise mapping for ...")?

Thanks

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue.  Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What routes are being generated? Run rake routes to find out.

If you are not seeing the routes that you expect, try defining your custom routes on a as block after your devise_for statement. Such as

```
devise_for :users, skip => [ :passwords, :registrations, :confirmations]

as :user do
    post   "account/password" => "devise/passwords#create"
    get    "account/password/new" => "devise/passwords#new" 
    get    "account/password/edit" => "devise/passwords#edit" 
    put    "account/password" => "devise/passwords#update"
...

end
```

You might also need to customize the views to point to the new paths that you declared.  Look at Devise wiki to find how to customize views.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `:controllers => { :passwords => "devise/passwords"}` option

Answer (score 1):

I tested your routes and I got this on a `rake routes`:

```
account_password POST   /account/password(.:format)      {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"create"}
    new_password GET    /account/password/new(.:format)  {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"new"}
   edit_password GET    /account/password/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"edit"}
                 PUT    /account/password(.:format)      {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"update"}
         account POST   /account(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
         sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
                 DELETE /account(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
    confirmation POST   /confirmation(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
new_confirmation GET    /confirmation/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"devise/confirmations", :action=>"new"}
                 GET    /confirmation(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
new_user_session GET    /sign_in(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    user_session POST   /sign_in(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

destroy_user_session DELETE /sign_out(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}

So, I guess you should be using `user_session_path`(without any argument) on your `form_for`. If you put the user as an argument, Rails will think it is the format and it will not work.